# Migrate files to a new database using Laravel Migrations

Tags: laravel, migration

So I have a lot of migration files from a previous database setup. I'd like to apply these files to a new database. For example, if I were starting from scratch I would do something like this:

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
```

and then:

```
php artisan migrate
```

for every single migration file. But since I already have all the migration files, is there a way to skip all of the make:migration part and get it to create the corresponding tables?

I've tried:

```
php artisan migrate --force
```

but it doesn't work. What's the right way to do this? This is a clean installation of Laravel 5.5.

I'm getting this error:

[image]

This is the schema where the error is happening:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('email')->unique();

            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();

            $table->timestamp('created_at');
            $table->timestamp('updated_at');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: Try: `$table->timestamp('created_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
$table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));`

Comment: Have you tried like my above comment?

Comment: I just tried. It's the same error unfortunately.

Comment: You probably have NO_ZERO_DATE(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) enabled in your MySQL configuration. Setting this to off will allow you to create the table or alternatively remove the default 0 value or change it to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp).

Comment: Interesting theory... I think it may hold some promise. How would I allow zero dates?

Comment: I have provided URL for both, please visit it.

Comment: I did read it. I just don't see any instructions on how to disable it. I'm using MySQL 5.7.2 so it's definitely possible that that's the problem.

Comment: Firstly, Can you plz check one time this: `'mysql' => array(
   'strict'    => true
),` in your `config/database.php`??

Comment: Hmm, I just checked. It's set to false.

Comment: Do it 'true' and then check plz! Hope it's works!

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to post comments so posting this as an answer.

try **$table->timestamps();**

Don't write created_at and updated_at separately.

Also try this:-

`$table->string('remember_token', 100) -> nullable();`

This seems to be the last hope now.

try `$table->timestamps() -> nullable();`

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. I'm not sure why the schema wouldn't work in the first place since the edit you provided is exactly the same as the default schema example.

Comment: This worked $table->timestamps(); I didn't have the 's' at the end. Thanks!

Comment: It's interesting because in Laravel 5.3 the 2 columns are separate but in 5.5 you have to use ->timestamps();

Comment: `timestamps` is just created_at and updated_at as timestamp nullable

Comment: you don't **have** to use it .. it is a convenience .. it is just  `$table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable(); $table->timestamp....`

Comment: Ah, I see. Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: `$table->timestamps()->nullable()`  `timestamps` returns `void` so that would be an error

Answer (score 0):

Set strict to `true` in my MySQL config (in `.env` or `config/database.php`).

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => true
    ]
],
```

Comment: I have already gave my comment with this, not worked for OP. Plz read above conversation!